# Angular - Cannot find a differ supporting object 'Item One' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Several Questions on StackOverflow are similar to this one, but could not find a matching solution.

My code works fine when trying to fetch items into a "Select" control, I get successful result if items count is greater than 1, but the weird thing, if the returned data contains only one item I get a console error pointing to the template code and saying:

> Cannot find a differ supporting object 'Item One' of type 'string'.
>   NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Here is My Html code:

```
      <mat-select [formControl]="itemControl" required [(value)]="itemValue">
        <mat-option>--</mat-option>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item">{{item}}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
```

The component:

```
export class LoginWithDbComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  . . .
  items: string[] = [];
  itemValue: string;

  constructor(
    . . .
    public authService: AuthService,
  ) {

  }

  login(): void {
    this.authService.login(this.getUserLogin()).subscribe(
      next => {
        this.getUserItems();
      },
      error => {
      . . .
    );    
  }

  getUserItems() {
    this.items= this.authService.userItems;
    return this.items|| []; 
  }
```

And the service:

```
    export class AuthService {
      userItems: any = [];
      . . .
      login(model: any) {
        return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'login', model).pipe(
          map((response: any) => {
            const user = response;
            if (user) {
              this.decodedToken = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(user.token);
              this.userItems = this.decodedToken['items'];
              console.log(this.userItems);              <--- shows 'Item One'
            }
          })
        );
      }
      . . .
    }
```

So what should work for this particular case ?

Comment: Could you show userItems value in your AuthService after decodedToken?
Regards

Comment: @CharlySosa, a console.log(this.userItems) in AuthService just after the decodedToken shows correctly userItems value: 'Item One', please let me update the question.

Comment: It seems like the "items" token in the response to your "post" call may not be an array when there is only one item. You may need to check if `this.decodedToken['items']` is an array, and if not, add the single string to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the "items" token in the response to your "post" call is not an array when there is only one item. You may need to check if `this.decodedToken['items']` is an array, and if not, add the single string to an array.

```
let itemsToken = this.decodedToken['items'];
this.userItems = Array.isArray(itemsToken) ? itemsToken : [itemsToken];
```

Comment: Yes you're right, I've decoded manually the token from Postman, when there is only one item, it becomes a string instead of an array. Your tip works like a charm, thanks a lot Andrew :)